# Is it possible to create a macro that changes when $\mathrm$ is applied to it?

Tags: math-mode, macros

I would like to define a macro

```
\newcommand{\III}{I\hspace{-0.2em}I\hspace{-0.2em}I}
```

in such a way that when I type

```
$ \mathrm{\III} $
```

in math-mode, the compiler will compile

```
$ \mathrm{I\hspace{-0.05em}I\hspace{-0.05em}I} $
```

instead. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Are you planning to use `\III` in math mode not inside `\mathrm`?

Comment: Yes I am indeed.

Comment: So what’s the reason for using the same name for two distinct things?

Comment: I would like to treat III as a symbol, but with good spacing properties. The spacing in my definition makes the mathrm form look way too compact.

Comment: You said (in a comment to an answer that has now been deleted) that you need to use your `\III` symbol both in italic and in upright shape: did you consider inputting it as `$\mathit{\III}$` (and *not* just as `$\III$`) when you want it to appear in italic, and as `$\mathrm{\III}$` when you want it to be upright?  I’m saying this because I suspect that you are tampering with the space only in order to compensate for the fact that `$\III$` uses wider characters than `$\mathit{\III}$`.

Comment: it is very odd to use em spacing in math (since that is the space of the outer text font, are you sure you do not just want `\mathit{III}` as @GuM suggests?

Answer (score 4):

You can set a spacing for the case when `\mathnormal` is in force and less space for other math groups.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\III}{{I\IIIspace I\IIIspace I}}
\newcommand{\IIIspace}{%
  \mspace{%
    \ifnum\mathgroup=-1
      -5mu
    \else
      -2mu
    \fi
  }%
}

\begin{document}

$\III\ne\mathrm{\III}\ne\mathbf{\III}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

A different implementation, where in case of `\mathnormal` we use `\mathit` (and suppress the italic correction by inserting a suitable subscript that nullifies `\scriptspace`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\III}{%
  \ifnum\mathgroup=-1
    \expandafter\mathit
  \fi
  {I_{\kern-\scriptspace}\mspace{-2mu}I_{\kern-\scriptspace}\mspace{-2mu}I}%
}

\begin{document}

$\III\ne\mathrm{\III}\ne\mathbf{\III}$

$\scriptstyle\III\mathrm{\III}\mathbf{\III}$

$\scriptscriptstyle\III\mathrm{\III}\mathbf{\III}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Although I don't understand why a symbol should change shape.

Comment: Italic correction between the “I”s?  But `cmti10`’s `\fontdimen2` is not zero (cf. Appendix G, Rule 17).

Comment: @GuM Did you try it? See rule 14.

Comment: Yes, I tried it and I got `.\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 I .\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 I .\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 I .\kern1.58055` (from `\showlists`, *after* conversion from math to horizontal, newlines replaced by spaces); that is, no italic correction between the “I”s.  By Rule 14, the “I”s *are* marked as text symbols, plus `\fontdimen2` of `cmti10` is not zero, so in Rule 17 delta is set to zero, not to the italic correction.

Comment: @GuM Did you try with a math kern in between?

Comment: Oh, right: you are using a math kern… which I was not!  You see, the point is that everybody here expects that no answers of yours is less than perfect, so when I see something that looks strange or superfluous (because I have not understood it), I immediately ask—and I never regret to, since I’m always put back on the right track.

Answer (score 3):

You can test the current value of `\fam` register:

```
\def\III{I\ikern I\ikern I}
\def\ikern{\mkern-\ifnum\fam<0 4.5mu\else 1.5mu \fi}

$\III \quad \rm \III$

\bye
```

Comment: Do you see any significant difference with my answer, apart using plain TeX that's apparently not the OP's aim?

Comment: Significant difference is: `\mathgroup` works only in LaTeX but `\fam` works in all TeX formats (inluding LaTeX, of course). I don't understand why LaTeX says `\let\mathgroup=\fam` and introduces new functionless terminology.

Answer (score 0):

To answer what your title ask:

I do not dare to recommend this since `\mathrm` doesn't take any arguments, I suspect something bad happens.

Both examples below prints `hello world`

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \newif\ifMathrm
  \newcommand\mathrmNew[1]{\Mathrmtrue\mathrm{#1}\Mathrmfalse}
  \newcommand\hello{\ifMathrm world\else hello\fi}
  \[ \hello~\mathrm{\hello} \]
\end{document}
```

It would be a little bit better to make `\mathrmNew` that toggles a flag. This is better because it doesn't execute the if-statements everytime `\mathrm` is called. Like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \newif\ifMathrm
  \newcommand{\mathrmNew}[1]{\Mathrmtrue\mathrm{#1}\Mathrmfalse}
  \newcommand{\hello}{\ifMathrm world\else hello\fi}
  \[ \hello~\mathrmNew{\hello} \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Since I don’t know, what exactly goes wrong if I try your second (non) suggestion?

Comment: Nothing really goes wrong. I think? But since the definition of `\mathrm` doesn't take any arguments, I suspect you're doing something bad. I'll ask the kings around here, maybe they know if this actually is bad?